# PHP - Twig Installation

Tags: php, smarty, twig

I've been looking at Twig (http://twig.sensiolabs.org/).  I've been wanting to make a simple open source calendar program that I can distribute (has a mini installer etc).  Smarty (another template engine) wants you to install it in a non web-accessible directory for security.  The only thing is I'd think that would make my installer really complicated if not impossible.  Does twig require you to place its main files outside the webroot, or can I place it anywhere?

Comment: If you plan to distribute it (and if not done already) please always research for existing implementations and consider contributing to them instead of creating a new one from scratch. For instance this [php-calendar](http://code.google.com/p/php-calendar/) project looks active. That said, I do not want to discourage or censor your project and wish you luck either with creating a new one or contributing to an existing open source project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither Smarty nor Twig *require* you to store them anywhere specific. Both are *recommended* to be stored outside the doc-root for security reasons. not more. not less.

Comment: but posting them in the webroot would be unwise?  Would it be possible to make a web-based self-installer that placed them outside the webroot?

Comment: That really depends on the environment you want to install into. It won't kill you if you have all libraries accessible in your web-root. You could try to block access with an .htaccess file or something